# How to say "ask someone out" in context of dating in German

Tags: english-to-german

Is "Nur fragen sie heraus" an accurate way to say "Just ask her out" in reference to dating?

I am under the impression that "heraus" is more of an action as opposed to "out" in the sense of "outdoors." Because I am not trying to say "Just ask her to go camping."

The phrase that I am working on is meant to be a quick informal push to tell someone to just make a move in a flirting context.

Answer (score 14):

You translate single English words into  German. "Nur fragen sie heraus" sounds like a computer translation ten years ago. In the meantime computer translations have become better. Your German sentence is incomprehensible, even if the translation for the single words is correct.

The sentence might be:

> Frag sie einfach, ob sie mit dir ausgehen will.

Comment: This sentence has a lot more words, so I think it focuses more on communicating a concept. What would the equivalent translation be back to English?

Comment: A literal translation would be: Just ask her that her whether she wants to go out with you.

Comment: I see there is a typo in my sentence. Correct:  Just ask her whether she wants to go out with you.

Answer (score 3):

As German, I would say the best translation is: "Frage sie doch einfach mal."

Comment: Just curious how they would differ

Comment: @JGallardo... how who would differ?

Comment: @Lorenz: Was soll ich sie denn fragen? It sounds to me that you didn't understand the original "Just ask her out", translates to "Frag sie einfach, ob ihr mal ausgehen wollt".

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar: I thought you were already in a conversation about going out with a girl.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real equivalent of the beautiful short "ask out" in german. You have multiple options:

```
to ask out = nach einem Date fragen / sie um ein Date bitten
to ask out = fragen, ob sie mit <person> ausgehen will
to ask out = um ein Rendezvous bitten
```

and for the exact translation

```
Just ask her out = Frag´ sie einfach nach einem Date
Just ask her out = Frag´ sie einfach, ob sie mit dir ausgehen möchte
Just ask her out = Bitte sie einfach um ein Rendezvous
```

as you see, first and last options have English or French words inside. That might indicate that asking out is not a german tradition...

First and second option are the most common ones, though the first became more popular. Last one is very polite and may be considered conservative.